# Saving Twitter Like Hashtags with Regex Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, tags, hashtag

Thanks for your help!
I'm trying to save twitter like hashtags in my rails app. Users enter their tags prepended by the #hashtag symbol. However, it keeps saving empty strings. I added an additional unless statement to combat it, but now it doesn't save any tags.
Code:

```
def tag_list=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(/\B#\w+/).map do |n|
    unless n.strip == "" || n.strip == nil
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

I've also tried the following regex which also return the same:

```
/\B#\w+/

/(?:^|\s)(?:(?:#\d+?)|(#\w+?))\s/i

/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/i
```

Comment: [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) might be a more appropriate tool for this than [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split). You're not really trying to *split* the string into pieces, you're trying to *scan* the string to find certain patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex works totally, but you must use `scan` instead of `split`, so your code to assign the tags would be:

```
def tag_list=(names)
  self.tags = names.scan(/\B#\w+/).map do |tag|
    Tag.find_or_initialize_by(name: tag.remove('#'))
  end
  save!
end
```

The changes are:

- Use `scan`
- Use `find_or_initialize_by` instead of `where` then `first_or_create!`
- Use `save!` at the end to save once
- You may not need `tag.remove('#')` if you want to save the hashtag with `#` prefix